Probability Density Function Increasing Faster and with Heavier Tail
Fix $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma > 0$. The density $f$ of the $\text{Lognormal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution is :
\begin{equation*}
f(x) =  \frac{1}{x \sigma \sqrt{2  \pi}}  \exp\{ -\frac{( \ln x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\} \chi_{(0, \infty)}(x)
 \end{equation*}
It is unimodal, because it has one clear peak. Fix $t \in (0,\infty)$ such that $f(t)$ is the peak. We call $(0,t)$ the increasing region and $(t , \infty)$ the decreasing region. Is there any explicit probability density function $g$ such that :

$g$ is continuously differentiable and supported in $(0,\infty)$.
$g$ is unimodel, with the peak also attained at $t$.
If $x \neq t$, then $g'(x) > f'(x)$ always holds.
$\int_0^{\infty}x g(x) dx < \infty$.

In words, what I want is an explicit probability density function such that it increases steeper than $f$ in the increasing region and it decreases slower than $f$ in the decreasing region, while still being integrable. There is obviously infinitely many such $g$.  To answer the question, name any explicit formula of $g$ would be fine .

Edit : as pointed out in comments, it is unlikely that property 3 holds. In that case, a solution with property 1, 2, and 4 holding with approximately faster increase and heavier tail will be accepted.

Since $\int_0^\infty(g-f)dx=0$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty}(g-f)=0$, how can $g-f$ be increasing?

You are right. Maybe I have some mistake in the formulation. But look at the description in words. I want it to increase faster and have a heavier tail, although peak may be smaller than lognormal density. As long as this is approximately the case in the graph, I will accept the answer.
